# How to force a clean Azure WebSite deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I deploy an Azure Website using VS2013, to a test website and to a production website. The two have identical settings (different domain of course) - There is one feature that doesn't work only in production.

I (strongly) suspect that there is an old 3rd party dll (related to that feature) on the production bin folder that causes trouble.

There is no RDP for Azure Websites, so I can't confirm.

Is there a way to force Azure to publish the website to a clean folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean Windows Azure Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476525/clean-windows-azure-website)

Comment: A better answer is available in this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17476525/230428 I have nominated this question to be closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Windows Azure Web Sites you can't RDP, but you can use FTP to see if the DLL in question is in the bin directory.  You might try that.

The FTP URI can be seen on the management portal.  The credentials are the same as your deployment credentials.  Make sure to login in the user as Sitename\username.