# Publishing resource files of ASP.NET MVC application on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5, resources

I'm working on a web application in C# with the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I publish my work on Azure and everything seems te work fine. Except when I Change something in one of my Resources Files (strings). I can see the changes locally, but not on Azure. Adding new strings works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your publish settings aren't removing or updating the resource files.  Try this:

[Clean Windows Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476525/clean-windows-azure-website/17552723#17552723)