# Azure Web Site not updating via Visual Studio Web Deploy

Tags: visual-studio, azure, web-deployment, webdeploy

This may be a basic question, but I've searched for a little while and couldn't find anything specific to this.

I bought a domain and created the web app in Azure for hosting, and set up the DNS so that it's linked to the Azure Web App. Using Visual Studio 15, I opened the website via the FTP connection settings found in Azure, and was able to create files, edit the html, css, etc. Going forward, I wanted to use Web Deploy with Visual Studio to push new builds of the code up to the web site. I downloaded the publish profile from Azure, and imported it into a new visual studio project. I also copied all the previous files over(it wasn't alot). I got the correct Web Deploy settings and successfully published the solution to the Web App in Azure. However, it never updates the code with my new changes. When I look at the site in Firebug it still has the same files/code that it had when I edited it via FTP.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I followed your steps and everything published perfectly for me. Did you try to simply refresh the file list to make sure Visual Studio is seeing all your files? Are they included in your project?

Also, when you go to publish, on the 4th step labeled preview, try to hit "start preview" and see if it detects any changes.

[image: Publish Preview in VS2015]

Also, could you tell me a bit more about your project? Is it a website project folder, mvc solution, etc?

Comment: Here are the steps I took after setting up the DNS/Azure settings for the domain and web app. 

 1. Opened a "web site" in VS, connected via FTP settings for the web app. Created files and a few lines of html just as a test. 
2. Saved in VS, verified the website updated with my changes. 
3. Dowloaded the publish profile from the Azure Web App
4. Created a new project in VS, imported the web app publish profile
5. Created files and added code, published the build. Publish succeed. The website however doesn't update with my changes since switching to web deploy from FTP.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio is seeing the files. I have it saved as a solution in my OneDrive folder. I have verified that on my 2 different computer OneDrive is in sync and is seeing the same files/code. When I click Preview, it does detect the changes from my last publish. I get the Publish Succeeded as well. My website just never updates from first save I had made via FTP.

I'm guessing something happened when I changed over to saving via FTP, to using web deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clean the website to make sure your new files are getting deployed.

[Clean Windows Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476525/clean-windows-azure-website/17552723#17552723)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did this, now when I go to my URL I get an error message saying: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."